# Unable to remove GameObjects from List<>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an ecology predator-prey balance simulator. Using Vuforia me and my project group want to simulate the effects of forest fires, hunters, etc. to the population sizes (on a small scale). For this I need to be able to manually add and remove deer and wolves. Don't ask why we chose deer and wolves.

I used `OnGui()` to add 4 buttons, a plus and minus for adding and removing deer, and likewise for the wolves. [Here's what the buttons look like on the top of my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYcL.png) The buttons do manage to *add* the animals and also to *remove* the *first* manually added animal. Pingponging between no animals and 1 can go on forever, but second or any animals added after consecutively can't be removed with the press of the minus sign. I am confused as to why.

Below I have posted my `OnGui()` method in its entirety. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way the List<> works.

```
void OnGUI()
    {
        // Add deer.
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(marginLeft, marginTop, size, size), plus, GUIStyle.none))
        {
            GameObject newDeer = Instantiate(deerPrefab, deerSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
            deerList.Add(newDeer);
        }

        // Remove deer.
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(marginLeft, marginTop + marginBetween + size, size, size), minus, GUIStyle.none))
        {
            Debug.Log("Amount of deer in the list: " + deerList.Count);
            GameObject removeDeer = deerList[deerList.Count - 1];
            Destroy(removeDeer);
            Debug.Log("Removing deer. " + deerList.Count + " deer left.");
        }

        // Add wolf.
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - marginLeft - size, marginTop, size, size), plus, GUIStyle.none))
        {
            GameObject newWolf = Instantiate(wolfPrefab, wolfSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
            wolvesList.Add(newWolf);
        }

        // Remove wolf.
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - marginLeft - size, marginTop + marginBetween + size, size, size), minus, GUIStyle.none))
        {
            Debug.Log("Amount of wolves in the list: " + wolvesList.Count);
            GameObject removeWolf= wolvesList[wolvesList.Count - 1];

            Destroy(wolvesList.Last());
            Debug.Log("Removing wolf. " + wolvesList.Count + " wolves left.");
        }

    }
```

If you want any other information to help solve the problem, I'll be more than happy to provide you with that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stop using OnGui and use the [new UI system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Comment: While I see the `.Add` calls, I don't see any calls to remove anything from `wolvesList` or `deerList`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using your list in Unity, but try not only destroying you GameObject, try to also remove it from the list: `wolvesList.Remove(removeWolf)`.

Comment: Destroy does not remove things from your list, you need to remove it manually.

Comment: So dumb, I had removed the .Remove() calls for debugging earlier. Thanks for the quick response, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line here, you are assigning the last deer in the List to a new gameobject (which is separate from the List), and then removing it from the *scene* with Destroy().

```
GameObject removeDeer = deerList[deerList.Count - 1];
```

If you want to remove the deer from the List itself you should be doing:

```
deerList.RemoveAt(deerList.Count - 1);
```

or some other variation of List.Remove();

Comment: Ironically enough, I had removed the .Remove() calls earlier for debugging purposes. Since I forgot I had removed them, I didn't think to check for them. It's the little things that can sometimes keep you busy the longest.

Comment: the little ones always seem to be the worst bugs!